# My code is running fine but I don't know why it shows 16 instead of (16, 2)?

Tags: python

The answer always comes out to be 16 but what happens to the `x` in function `sq(func,x)` because `func` turned into 16 but `x` remains 2. So it should show something like 16, 2 when I try to print it.

```
def sq(func,x):
    y = x**2
    return func(y)

def f(x):
    return x**2

Calc = sq(f,2)
print(Calc)
```

Comment: `x` is 2, that's correct. Now where in your code do you believe `x` is being printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your print statement prints cal, which is the number returned by the function f(x), which is what is returned by the function sq(f,y).

If you want to print the structure that you need, try to do the following:

```
def sq(func,x):
    y = x**2
    return (func(y), x)

def f(x):
    return x**2

Calc = sq(f,2)
print(Calc)
```